# Setting a different Rails template if a user is logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, layout

I am trying to set the layout to "private" when the user is logged in. It would be perfect if I could do something like:

```
layout 'private' if current_user
```

Except it gives this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `current_user' for ApplicationController:Class
```

I've also tried doing this in the application controller:

```
before_filter :pick_the_layout

def pick_the_layout
  if current_user
    render :layout => "private"
  else
    render :layout => "public"
  end
end
```

No luck with that one, either, which makes sense. Can anyone think of a better way to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
layout :determine_layout

private
  def determine_layout
    current_user ? "private" : "public"
  end
```

Obviously, this depends on `current_user` being `nil` or `false` if the user is not logged in.

You can see documentation for the usage of `layout` here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Layouts/ClassMethods.html#method-i-layout

and here with more examples:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Layouts.html

Comment: Awesome. This works perfectly and I love how clean it is. I never thought of setting the layout like that. Thanks a bunch for the help (and for the links, too).

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... maybe 
`layout 'private' if defined?(current_user)`?

Comment: Well, that didn't give any errors, but it didn't render anything, either. Thanks, though.